# What does +number in the stack trace mean

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I have an error and this is shown:

```
[OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.]
System.Decimal..ctor(Double value) +0
System.Decimal.op_Explicit(Double value) +30
MyMethod(int myParameter) +5174
AnotherMethod(int myParameter) ....
```

What does +5174 mean?
It's not a line number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be the IL offset, this happens when no PDB files / debug information are present.

You can have PDB data generated for release assemblies, which makes tracking down issues much more straight forward.